# how to find/replace string in file

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to find in file this string:

```
"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":3,"Login":3,"*":3}
```

and replace it with this string:

```
"cPHulk":{"*":"1","Login":"1","BruteForce":"1"}
```

I'm using sed to do this but I struggle a lot. My sed command is as follow:

```
sed -i -e 's/"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":3,"Login":3,"*":3}/"cPHulk":{"*":"1","Login":"1","BruteForce":"1"}/g' /var/cpanel/icontact_event_importance.json
```

EDIT:
The correct sed formula:

```
sed -i -e 's/"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":3,"Login":3,"\*":3}/"cPHulk":{"\*":"1","Login":"1","BruteForce":"1"}/g' /var/cpanel/icontact_event_importance.json
```

Comment: Exactly HOW is that sed command not working?

Comment: The command not replacing "cPHulk":{"BruteForce":3,"Login":3,"*":3} with what I want.

Comment: Replace in your sed command `*` by `\*`.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. This make the trick

Answer (score 0):

I found on some *nix you must provide a blank as the suffix to get it make an in-place replacement:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/"cPHulk":{"BruteForce":3,"Login":3,"*":3}/"cPHulk":{"*":"1","Login":"1","BruteForce":"1"}/g' /var/cpanel/icontact_event_importance.json
```

Note the `''` after `-i`

Comment: @hek don't shoot the messenger

Comment: I'm getting error: sed: can't read : No such file or directory